# Android lib to read or parse shapefile

Tags: android, shapefile

is there any library that is able to read parse a .shp file, preferably on where I don't need to use NDK.
I was trying to use GeoTools but i can't seam to get it to work on Android.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been using two lightweight shapefile parsers with good results in Android: [diewald_shapeFileReader](https://github.com/diwi/diewald_shapeFileReader) and [Java ESRI Shape File Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javashapefilere/).

[GeoTools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTools) relies heavily on [AWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit) and Java Service Provider Interface ([SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface)) both not supported by Android. So it´s not a viable option.

**EDIT 2021**

[Osmdroid](http://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/) library as of Mar 24st, 2019, Release: 6.1.0,

supports [overlaying shapefiles](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/osmdroid-shape) using the Java ESRI Shape File Reader I mentioned previously.

Syntax:

```
List<Overlay>  folder = ShapeConverter.convert(mMapView, new File(myshape));
mMapView.getOverlayManager().addAll(folder);
mMapView.invalidate();
```

Where

> myshape is a .shp file somewhere on the drive. If other metadata files
> are found, they will be used and injected into the converted shapes.

Comment: please, tell me what are using to display .shp file eg. OSM or any other library, i need to implementation in my project.

Comment: After parsing how will I display it on Google Maps??

Comment: @LuísTavares  how can we create files such as (.cpg, .dbf, .prj, .shp, .shx ) on Android application. Any suggested lib??  Thank you !

Comment: @LuísTavares thank you! Any other option? I mean can we create these files (.cpg, .dbf, .prj, .shp, .shx ) without using Android NDK on android application project?

Comment: @LuísTavares Thank You !! I appreciate your help !!