# Displaying shapefile maps in android application

Tags: android, osmdroid, shapefile, mapsforge

I'm currently developing maps application for Android. I have map that I want to display in shapefile format (actually it's group of shapefiles). As I understood shapefile is quite unusual way to store full map data but I have to deal with it somehow. So basically I just need to display shapefiles data in my application. Does anybody know any free map engine that can display shapefile data? I have already tried `osmdroid` and `mapsforge` but these tools does not seems to support shapefiles, if I'm wrong link to some sample will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to display `Shape` file format in `Maps` in `Android`. But i have implemented to select a shape file and  convert it into KML format and then made one `KML Parser` that will manage all the projections data.

There is also another way by using `GeoTools` you can handle Shape file but i dont it works in Android.

Here is another post in SO so try any one [Android lib to read or parse shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548044/android-lib-to-read-or-parse-shapefile)

Comment: Well, I have this map converted in KML and KMZ format too but this KML file is bigger than 140 MB.  I have tried to display this KML with `osmbonuspack` but it seems that it can't deal with such big files.

Comment: Could you advise me a common approach of dealing with such a big maps?

Comment: @Bersh Sorry budy i have no idea for that.