# Android : Shapefile in Googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, gis, shapefile

I'm Developing an app with **Google Maps**. In which i need to show a layer of data from the **shape file** or **imagery**.

Do any one has an idea on how to do it, i have no idea how to project the layer over the Google maps in android.

Provide me with some API and sample codes if available else with any other suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to render `.Shp` file directly in Google Maps.

But if you really want to do then export `.Shp` to `.Kml` file using some **QuantumGIS or ARC GIS** and then Make `XMLPullParser` that can easily parse this `.Kml` file.

Refer this questions for more information

[Does anyone know of a library in Java that can parse ESRI Shapefiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044876/does-anyone-know-of-a-library-in-java-that-can-parse-esri-shapefiles)

[Android lib to read or parse shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548044/android-lib-to-read-or-parse-shapefile)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48191/how-to-display-esri-shapefile-in-android

https://gist.github.com/kiichi/6119073

Answer (score 2):

With [Google Maps Android API utility library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) you can display KML or GeoJSON data over a Google Maps MapView.

Now you only need to parse your shapefile and convert it to one of the previous mentioned formats.

The shapefile parsing process can be accomplished with one of the libraries mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548044/android-lib-to-read-or-parse-shapefile).

The conversion process (java objects to XML or JSON objects) will need to be programmatically handled by you.