# Display ShapeFiles with WhirlyGlobe

Tags: java, android, gis, shapefile

can anyone tell me how to display local shapefiles in Android with the WhirlyGlobe SDK?

I'm using readFromFile but I get always false.
http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/reference/android_2_5/index.html

My Code: string is the path to the folder with the shapefiles

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {

    VectorInfo vectorInfo = new VectorInfo();
    vectorInfo.setColor(Color.RED);
    vectorInfo.setLineWidth(4.f);

    VectorObject object = new VectorObject();

    File fileShape = new File(string + "/poly.shp");

    String shapefile = "";
    if (fileShape .exists()){
        shapefile = fileShape.getAbsolutePath();
    }



    if(object.readFromFile(shapefile)){
        controller.addVector(object,vectorInfo,MaplyBaseController.ThreadMode.ThreadAny);
    }

    //if (object1.fromGeoJSON(shapefile)) {
    //   controller.addVector(object, vectorInfo, MaplyBaseController.ThreadMode.ThreadAny);
    //}
}
```

The example with GeoJSON works fine.
http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/tutorial/android/vector-data.html

Answer (score 1):

The `readFromFile` method you're trying to invoke is supposed to be used when reading a binary file previously written with the `writeToFile` method, as a way to cache data, and not for reading shapefiles, although shapefiles are binary files.

Since the GeoJSON example is working fine , and since there's no `fromShapeFile` method, your only alternative is to parse the shapefile and convert it to GeoJSON so that you can read it with the `fromGeoJSON` method.

[Android lib to read or parse shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548044/android-lib-to-read-or-parse-shapefile/)

Comment: My mistake, there is a fromShapefile method but not in the 2.5 version. You can download aar 2.6.2 here http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/builds/builds.html